# React-native component SearchableDropdown from react-native-searchable-dropdown doest not fire onItemSelect={(item) => {console.log(item)}}

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to use `SearchableDropdown` from `react-native-searchable-dropdown` as adrop down select with auto completion. The event `onItemSelect` is supposed to be fired when select an element from dropdown list. But it does not trigger so.

```
import SearchableDropdown from 'react-native-searchable-dropdown';
import React, {Component} from 'react';

 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedId: 0,
    };
  }

...

export default class SearchComponent extends Component {

render() {
   return(
      <ScrollView>
        <SearchableDropdown
          onItemSelect={item => console.log(item)}
          containerStyle={{padding: 5}}
          itemStyle={{
            padding: 10,
            marginTop: 2,
            backgroundColor: 'white',
            borderColor: 'white',
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderRadius: 5,
          }}
          itemTextStyle={{color: 'black'}}
          itemsContainerStyle={{height: 220}}
          items={skills}
          resetValue={false}
          textInputProps={{
            placeholder: 'Placeholder',
            underlineColorAndroid: 'transparent',
            style: {
              padding: 12,
              borderWidth: 1,
              backgroundColor: 'white',
              borderColor: theme.colors.caption,
              borderRadius: 10,
            },
            onTextChange: text => alert(text),
          }}
          listProps={{
            nestedScrollEnabled: true,
          }}
        />
    </ScrollView>
)}
```

Can someone help me with the solution?

Comment: can you share your source code.

Comment: I have shared the relevant part. Is it not enough?

Comment: can you share your whole component or create a ```expo```sample

Comment: now you can see probably what you want

Comment: The following warning is shown when the curser is placed on the text input field. `VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews with the same orientation - use another VirtualizedList-backed container instead.`

Comment: The problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved. The reason was that `SearchableDropdown` was wrapped with a `ScrollView`. It does not support that. I don't know exactly what the reason was (if anyone can explain it, it would be usefull for others as well). But after replacing `ScrollView` with `SafeAreaView`, it was solved.

```
render() {
   return(
      <SafeAreaView>
        <SearchableDropdown
          onItemSelect={item => console.log(item)}
          ...
        />
      </SafeAreaView>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

This issue can also be fixed by adding this prop `keyboardShouldPersistTaps = 'always'`
to your ScrollView component.

This fixed the issue for me, See below:

```
render() {
   return(
      <ScrollView 
         keyboardShouldPersistTaps = 'always'>
        <SearchableDropdown
          onItemSelect={item => console.log(item)}
          ...
        />
      </ScrollView>
   )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add keyboardShouldPersistTaps = 'always' in scrollView, if not your SearchableDropdown selected item changed to null